# Windows 7 computer freezes even after a fresh install

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, freeze, fresh-install

I have a laptop that had a motherboard replaced and ever since my computer freezes every now and then. It so random that it makes it difficult to pinpoint the issue. Sometimes it freezes up at login screen and sometimes we can work on it for hours and nothing would happen.
First we thought it was a driver issue so we updated all the drivers from Dell website. Then we thought it could be one of the services so we did a clean boot but that didn't fix it. Then we did hardware diagnostics, chkdsk, sfc scannow to make sure it was nothing related to Hardware or Software.
Finally we thought it was Windows updates so I uninstalled most of the updates after fresh install but that doesn't seem to have fix it either.

Checked event viewer and there's nothing suspicious that points to this issue

It's a Dell Latitude 3450 with 64-bit Windows 7 on it.

Can anyone help??

Comment: If it didn't happen before motherboard replacement, then the replacement wasn't done correctly. The motherboard is faulty, not installed properly or some other component was damaged in the process. Complain to the person who did the repair.

Comment: It’s a hardware issue. The diagnostics you ran really doesn’t tell us anything. The motherboard was changed and ever since then it’s been locking up. It should’ve been addressed right away as a hardware issue surrounding the new motherboard.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It was a Dell technician who did this work. Since the laptop is still under warranty, I will ask them to send have it replaced once again.

Comment: But are there any chances that it could anything else?? I don't want to got to them without making sure that it was indeed the motherboard that is causing this issue and nothing else.

Comment: Can you expand on "freezes" -- what exactly are the conditions? Does the mouse pointer still move or not? Do you get a BSOD or Windows error message? Can you bring up Task Manager? When you say freezes at Login, can you type in the password box?

Comment: At login screen, I cannot enter anything. The keyboard doesn't work and the mouse pointer, well sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. But even though when it is working, I cannot seem to click on anything. Cannot bring task manager or explorer or anything. No error messages, no BSOD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's causing AppCrash and BSOD events, general instability?](https://superuser.com/questions/1282011/whats-causing-appcrash-and-bsod-events-general-instability)

Answer (score 1):

As it's pointed out in the comments this is probably a hardware issue. If you want to investigate more, I believe some error dumps are occasionally stored under c:\windows\minidump.

You could also check de Event Manager to see if there is any event that points out to the problem.

Overheating can be the issue too, maybe some cooler is not working correctly or stopping every now and then which would cause overheating and crashes at different moments.

If you know how, you could try using a Linux Live (Ubuntu or whichever you like) which doesn't need installing you can just boot up with it. If it crashes you can be sure it isn't related to Windows, it's a hardware issue.
If it does not crash.. Well maybe you were just lucky or maybe it's Windows related.

Since it's under warranty you should take it anyways, you aren't required to diagnose the problem, that's what they are there for. Good luck