# Characters appearing at random

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, lenovo-laptop, popups

I'm using Windows 10 on a Lenovo T460 and have been having an odd issue where "gg" appears at random. It is always the same two characters and there are certain things that sometimes trigger it but not always. If I have caps lock on it will appear as "GG" but otherwise is always in the two "g" format. It has been going on for months and happens wherever my cursor is located so it's not limited to a particular program.

Several things have been attempted to stop it including disabling the laptop keyboard, switching external keyboards, uninstalling keyboard in Device Manager, and updating BIOS to name a few. I've recently figured out a few triggers but it is not limited to these and will sometimes just occur. One main one is if I plug my phone in using the USB port, it almost always causes "gg" to appear. Unplugging my phone will also trigger it but not quite as frequently. I've also observed that pop ups for notifications (emails, messages, calendar alerts, news alerts) will often cause it. Again, they don't guarantee the appearance of "gg" but likely will happen together. The uninstalling keyboard seemed to work for a month or two but it is back to the point that it is difficult to do anything because I may miss the extra characters and it will cause problems.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Try booting into another OS (for example, using a Linux distro on a Live CD) and see if the problem still occurs. If yes, then you have defective hardware. If no, then software is your problem. This will greatly help focus your troubleshooting. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1282026/213131) for more

Comment: The phone points to possible RF interference, though the email issue does not... unless the phone is nearby. Try putting the phone a few meters away from the laptop *and from any wires or peripherals* connected to it. Intermittent issues are hard to resolve.

Comment: I unplugged and moved the phone but still had the issue pop up. I'm testing to see if it could possibly be my bluetooth headphones.